# How can I conditionally move rows between 3 sheets in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a list of tasks on a sheet, and I've been trying to find a simple way to move the rows with tasks to a different sheet depending on the status in one column (e.g. blank, done, paid). For instance, a task on row 2 is marked "done". I then need that row to be deleted and moved to the sheet labeled "done". From there, when the task is paid, i need that row deleted from the "done tab to the "paid" tab.

I've found some code that allows me to do this once for 1 row, but it doesn't repeat for the rows below it. Here is the code I've been using:

```
function ConditionalShimmy2(){
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

 var sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName('not done');
 var sheet2 = ss.getSheetByName('done');
 var sheet3 = ss.getSheetByName('paid'); 

  var cell = sheet1.getRange("f2:f277").getCell(1, 1);
  var rowtoInsert = "2:277"; 

 if(cell.getValue() == "done") 
 {

   sheet2.insertRows(2); 
   var range2 = sheet2.getRange(2 ,1,1,sheet1.getLastColumn()); 
  sheet1.getRange(cell.getRow(),1, 1, sheet1.getLastColumn()).copyTo(range2); 
  sheet1.deleteRow(cell.getRow()); 
 }
}
```

Can anyone help me finish this code and let me know where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

In order to achieve your task, you can try the below proposed **solution** that will suit your situation.

#### Snippet

```
function ConditionalShimmy2() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  var main = ss.getSheetByName("THE_NAME_OF_THE_MAIN_SHEET");
  var sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName("not done");
  var sheet2 = ss.getSheetByName("done");
  var sheet3 = ss.getSheetByName("paid");
  var taskNames = main.getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns).getValues();
  var taskStatus = main.getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns).getValues();
  var rowsDeleted = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < taskStatus.length; i++) {
    if (taskStatus[i][0] == "not done") {
      sheet1.appendRow([taskNames[i][0]]);
      main.deleteRow((i + 1) - rowsDeleted);
      rowsDeleted++;
    } else if (taskStatus[i][0] == "done") {
      sheet2.appendRow([taskNames[i][0]]);
      main.deleteRow((i + 1) - rowsDeleted);
      rowsDeleted++;
    } else if (taskStatus[i][0] == "paid") {
      sheet3.appendRow([taskNames[i][0]]);
      main.deleteRow((i + 1) - rowsDeleted);
      rowsDeleted++;
    }
  }
}
```

#### Explanation

The above snippet loops through all the tasks and their associated statuses and based on the `status` column, each row is then appended to the appropriate sheet by making use of the `appendRow()` method and then deleted from the `main` sheet by making use of the `deleteRow()` method.

#### Note

In order to make the above code snippet work for your situation, you will have to customize the parameters for the `getRange` method associated to both `taskNames` and `taskStatus`. Therefore, the `row`, `column`, `numRows`, `numColumns` parameters represent the range with the top left cell at the given coordinates with the given number of rows and columns.

#### Reference

- [Sheet Class - getRange()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column,-numrows,-numcolumns);
- [Sheet Class - appenRow()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#appendrowrowcontents);
- [Sheet Class - deleteRow()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#deleterowrowposition).